# MessageQueue.CanWrite always returns true

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, msmq

I have deselected the permissions for Send Message on a private queue, yet `MessageQueue.CanWrite` never returns `false`. I can toggle Receive Message permissions and the `CanRead` property responds as expected. Why would the `CanWrite` property behave differently?

I have tested this issue with a couple of different AD users and the results are the same.

Is there a different approach to validating whether a specific user account can send a mesage to a specific remote private queue?

```
public class SendBehavior : IMsmqRuleBehavior
{
    public bool Validate(string queuePath)
    {
        using (var queue = new MessageQueue(queuePath, QueueAccessMode.Send))
        {
            return queue.CanWrite;                                        
        }
    }
}

public class ReceiveBehavior : IMsmqRuleBehavior
{
    public bool Validate(string queuePath)
    {
        using (var queue = new MessageQueue(queuePath, QueueAccessMode.Receive))
        {
            return queue.CanRead;                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that if `QueueAccessMode.Send` is requested that `CanWrite` would likely be `true`. *(side question: did you toggle the 'Authenticated` check box for this queue)*

Comment: I considered that but the default QueueAccessMode is SendAndReceive and the CanRead test behaves as expected with the QueueAccessMode set to Receive.

Comment: Does `CanWrite` become `false` when you set `QueueAccessMode.Receive`? Because from my review of the `MessageQueue` class in ILSpy it seems that only your modes you give reflect those property values.

Comment: Also, does it fail when you send a message? It appears this would be key to determining if this is the expected behavior.

Comment: The Authenticated checkbox was not checked. It is now and there was no change in behavior.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, this behavior is *as intended* for `MessageQueue.CanWrite`. If you delve deep enough into the guts of the MessageQueue class, you'll find it creates some helper objects which influence the value of this property in the following manner:

1. If you pass `QueueAccessMode.Send` (or `SendAndReceive`), an internal access mode helper will be created which returns `true` if `(this.accessMode & QueueAccessMode.Send) != (QueueAccessMode)0`.
2. If #1 is `true`, it then attempts to open the queue to store it into the cache, using the access mode and sharing you have requested. At this point a call to the native method [`MQOpenQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms699817%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is made, which has the following in its remarks (emphasis mine):

   > If the access rights for opening the queue in the mode requested are not allowed for the calling application, the following two things can happen:
   >
   > - **If `dwAccess` is set to `MQ_SEND_ACCESS`, `MQOpenQueue` will succeed**, but errors will be returned when the application tries to send a message.
   > - If `dwAccess` is set to `MQ_PEEK_ACCESS` or `MQ_RECEIVE_ACCESS`, `MQOpenQueue` will fail and return `MQ_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (0xC00E0025). In this case a queue handle is not returned to `phQueue`.

Therefore, given a `QueueAccessMode.Send` (or `SendAndReceive`) with a valid queue name and sharing mode, it is my understanding that `CanWrite` will return `true`, even if you truly do not have access to send a message.

Basically it appears that you will only receive `CanWrite == false` if and only if:

1. You pass a `QueueAccessMode` which is not `Send` or `SendAndReceive`.

Comment: Thanks for digging into this. Why would toggling the Receive Message permissions on the queue result in a true/false toggle of the "CanRead" property and when I send a message to the queue, with Send disabled, the message never makes it to the queue but I'm not receiving an exception either. That seems strange to me. I would think that CanRead and CanWrite would behave in the same manner.

Comment: @ChadLazette: I wish I had a better answer for you, but from what I can see this behavior is not based on the real permissions of the queue on the other end.

Comment: Fair enough. I appreciate it. I'll have to come up with another way to verify whether a user can send a message.